# React Router v4 - page composition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Here is what I want to implement:

In the case of `/event` and `/customercenter`, the `header` and `footer` are shown and only the contents of the `main` tag are changed.

On the other hand, the `/login` and `/register` pages do not show the header and footer.

First of all, my website's page composition is as follows.

> /
>   -- /event
>   -- /customercenter
>   /login
>   /register

I do not seem to be solving the problem because I think I am misunderstanding the matching.

When one enters the `/event` page,
`/` Was basically a match, so I thought that the component rendered in `/` would be drawn.

So `/`, `/login` and `/register` are branched using `switch` and `exact`, and the pages to be rendered under `/` are simply configured in the form of `<Route path = {...} component = {...}`.

To implement this, I have tried to implement it by referring to other articles in the stack overflow, but for some reason the router can not catch components from `/register` and `/login`(instead it returns `null`).

In a nutshell:

- expected result : no header and footer on `/login` and `/register`
- current result  : `/login` and `/register` with no matching compoennt with header and footer.

following is my simplified code:

---

## index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

## App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

To make `/login` and `/register` avoid matching `/` I used `exact`. But it didn't match anything.

---

## Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <MainHeader />
            <AwesomeRouter />
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

## router.js

```
class AwesomeRouter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Route path='/event' component={Event}/>
              <Route path='/customercenter' component={CustomerCenter}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the '/' path to the bottom of the list and remove **exact** from the routes.

Therefore, if '/login' and '/register' don't match, then '/' will match:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

Your '/event' and '/customercenter' routes will then also match '/' as it is not set to an **exact** match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is the one that I already tried. 
If I do this, `/login` and `/register` is rendered properly, but `/event` and `/customercenter` not.

Comment: You can move your '/' route to the bottom and remove **exact**. This way the other routes in the **<Switch>** will match first.

Comment: It works! I didn't even think it was a matter of order. Great!